# Where should I install my auto layout constraints in a UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm subclassing `UIView` to build a custom control. Where do I want to add my layout constraints on subviews?

I've added them in init, but I don't think that's the appropriate place to do anything beyond initialization. I don't want to do in `layoutSubviews` because I'm concerned about subsequent calls recreating the constraints.

What's the right place for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of options here. I think both `initWithFrame:` and `layoutSubviews` (with appropriate checks to avoid double-adding) could work, but [`updateConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622512-updateconstraints) is the canonical place to install constraints on subviews. You'd also need to avoid double-adding there.

Comment: How do you avoid double adding? My gut says to use identifiers on the constraints and then check if those exist.

Comment: You can just hold a reference to the constraints, or have a boolean ivar.

Comment: When I try this (on an `@IBDesignable` `UIView` subclass added to a `UIStackView`, if it matters), the stack view's constraints go bananas.

Answer (score 0):

I create constraints and add them in the init family of methods, after creating my view hierarchy.